# Highcharts graph X-axis label for different date ranges

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I have written a below code which generates a area graph for selected dates (to and from dates).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        "series": [{
            "showInLegend": false,
            "color": "#D0D0D0",
            "name": "Revenue",
            "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}],
        "credits": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "chart": {
            "renderTo": "highchart_id",
            "defaultSeriesType": "area",
            "shadow": true
        },
        "title": {
            "text": null,
            "align": "center",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 20
        },
        "xAxis": {
            "type": "datetime",
            "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
                "month": "%e. %b",
                "year": "%b"
            },
            "labels": {
                "enabled": "false"
            }
        },
        "legend": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "yAxis": {
            "title": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "labels": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        },
        "plotOptions": {
            "area": {
                "stacking": "normal",
                "lineColor": "#3E3E3E",
                "lineWidth": 3,
                "marker": {
                    "lineWidth": "1",
                    "lineColor": "#3E3E3E",
                    "states": {
                        "hover": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "radius": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "series": {
                "pointStart": 1335823200000,
                "pointInterval": 86400000
            }
        }
    };
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});​
```

The interval of dates on x-axis is coming one day less. here the series value 2 is for 10 may whereas it is showing for 9 may in graph.

I am new to this highchart, can anybody advice the solution please and let me known if you need any more clarification on the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding this code before declaring the chart

```
Highcharts.setOptions({      
  time: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});
```

By default highchart used UTC times. By adding the code above it will use the time zone of the browser.

Comment: This is deprecated, now it needs to be done for each chart:
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});